# Spotlight does not open OneDrive folders in finder

Tags: finder, spotlight, ventura, onedrive

**Spotlight does not open OneDrive folders in finder**

I use many files and folders in OneDrive. Usally i do a spotlight search, type in the folder name, the folder icon is shown and I click Enter and the folder opens in Finder - yeah!
Since the Venture update that doesn't work anymore. Opening spotlight and typing in the name shows a OneDrive icon and when pressing Enter and nothing happens except spotlight closes. :-(
[image]

I tried to update OneDrive, reseted it, did a few newstarts, but nothing helped.
Searching in Finder works fine.
Maybe you can help me?

Comment: Confirmation. I get this behaviour with both OneDrive and Dropbox (both using Apple's Files on Demand).  I consider this a bug in Spotlight search and/or its interaction with Finder. Note that HoudahSpot (which uses the same Spotlight index) correctly opens OneDrive folders in Finder.

Comment: The same problem exists with files. Quicklook also fails.